# Can we test changes in interface orientation on iPad Simulator?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios4

Can we test changes in orientation on iPad Simulator?

Also can we test the variants of an orientation on iPad Simulator?

**For Example:**

Variants of UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait is

- UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait
- UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown

**Code**

```
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
     { 
                  return (interfaceOrientation ==  UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
     }
```

Comment: You do realize you can rotate the simulator, right? *Right?!*

Comment: I have tried with the code added above in my question but it doesnt show any changes when I try to test in iPad simulator and currently I am not having an iPad device to test on. So just wanted to whether there is some problem with the code or some limitation of iPad simulator?

Comment: @BoltClock: I have added the code now

Comment: @BoltClock : I tried rotating the simulator but doesnt change the orientation of my view. So can you please the code and tell wat could be wrong?

Comment: Do you mean when you rotate the simulator upside-down, your views don't rotate?

Comment: @BoltClock: Even when the interfaceorientation of the simulator is in `UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown` then too my view is not moving. As such it should rotate the view by 180 degrees. So is there some extra code required to rotate my view when interfaceorientation changes?

Comment: @BoltClock: Yup exactly. It does not rotate the views when interface orientation is upside-down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can rotate simulator using Command + Left/Right arrow.  However from my own experience it is not so precise as on real device (sometimes there are bugs that can be reproduced only on the real device, unfortunately...)  If your views do not rotate, that it surely problem in your code (check shouldRotateToDeviceOrientation)

Comment: @Max:  I tried rotating the simulator but doesnt change the orientation of my view

Comment: I have posted my code in my question above. Can you please tell me what could be wrong?

Comment: try to set Supported interface orientations in your info.plist

Comment: how is that to be done? I am new in iPad development. It would be great if you can give some more information on how to do that?

Comment: What exactly I need to add into my info.plist?

Comment: Find <YourProjectName>-Info.plist file in Resources group and add field named Supported interface orientations (and specify orientations you need).

Comment: try to return YES in every shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation  and  check what happens

Comment: Even this does not rotate my views. It remains the same. What could be the issue?

Comment: Hey Max, Thanks this worked!! Got it working by adding the Interface Orientation information in my info.plist and then Cleaning and Building my app. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the orientation of the simulator and hence its interface orientation also changes. So u surely can test them on simulator.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still struggling with this, I suggest you change your test to:

```
return ((interfaceOrientation ==  UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown));
```

I think this is two tests (hence the two sets of brackets).

Hope this helps